# Sqlite delete data from columns

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

I have a table with 4 columns like this:

```
Date           Col1          Col2        Col3

27/03/2012     data          data        data

28/03/2012     data          data        data
```

I want to delete data from Col1 and Col2 from the row where date is 27/03/2012. Can anybody tell me how the query must be made?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE Col1="27/03/2012" OR Col2="27/03/2012"
```

**Update in response to some clarifications:**

To set Col2 to NULL for a particular date:

```
UPDATE tableName SET Col2=NULL WHERE Date="27/03/2012"
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask my question clear. I want to delete the data from col1 and col2 from the row where the column date has the date 27/03/2012, which is in the same row. Hope its clear now what I want.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to find the row where `date` is `27/03/2012`. Do you then want to delete that row, or do you want to set the data in `col2` to `NULL` (or something else)?

Comment: Yes, first I want to find the row where date is 27/03/2012. And then I want to set the data in col2 to NULL.

Comment: Excellent. Fancy accepting the answer with the big tick too? :-)

Comment: I cannot vote up because I don't have enough reputations. I will do this later when I have enough reputations.